# SQL Error unknown column in where clause?

Tags: sql

Write a query to display hotel id, hotel name, and number of orders taken by hotels that have taken orders more than 5 times. Give an alias name for number of orders as 'NO_OF_ORDERS'.sort the result based on hotel id in ascending order.

[Data Base Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WiGq.png)

The Query I wrote:

```
select hotel_details.hotel_id, hotel_name, count(orders.hotel_id) as no_of_orders 
from hotel_details join orders on hotel_details.hotel_id = orders.hotel_id
where no_of_orders > 5
group by orders.hotel_id order by no_of_orders;
```

Error I go:

```
unkown column 'number_of_orders' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `HAVING` clause, not a `WHERE` clause:

```
select
    hd.hotel_id,
    hd.hotel_name,
    count(o.hotel_id) as no_of_orders 
from hotel_details hd
inner join orders o on hd.hotel_id = o.hotel_id
group by
    o.hotel_id
having
    no_of_orders > 5
order by
    no_of_orders;
```

The count of orders occurs during the `GROUP BY` portion of the query, at which point `WHERE` has already happened.  So, assertions on anything from `GROUP BY` belong in a `HAVING` clause.